# Extracting the coefficients from the model Summary to make a equation

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am working on a problem and I use Multiple Regression to solve this problem.
R Square is 92%. VIF is pretty good. RMSE is okay. I need to make an equation with the coefficients from the summary. It's log log Regression.

Model Summary:

[image]

I want to make an equation with which I can actually predict the Price to test the model.

Answer (score 0):

`(summary(model2)$coef)[,]` You can use the square brackets to index the coefficients table and get the values that you need, directly.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I use these coefficients to predict the Price, because i used Log ?

Comment: you can convert the log of x back to its actual value by using `exp(x) `

Comment: Please elaborate, how can i back transform the variables from log. Thank you

Comment: `exp(log(VDP)) = VDP`  If you get log(VDP) in the output, then convert back to VDP by wrapping it with `exp()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
modl = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

alpha = modl.intercept_
betas = modl.coef_

print(f'alpha = {modl.intercept_}')
print(f'betas = {modl.coef_}')
```

Where the equation is predicted_value_y =  alpha + beta1*x1 + beta2 * x2 .....

Note: 1. You cant achieve the equation if you are using any other algorithm other than linear regression. 
 2. Don't scale the x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test variables, use the actual data to get coefficients which actually predict the next real-time data. If you scale, then the coefficients will also be scaled. Such an equation cannot be used to predict new unscaled data.

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you. So technically this equation wont predict the Price ? I didn't get you. I want to make an equation with all the coefficients and intercepts so that i can predict the price easily in future.

Comment: equation is as mentioned in the ans
price = alpha + beta1 * variable1 + beta2* variable2 ..... 

if u have the variable values, u can obtain alpha beta from above piece of code and compute the equation.

Comment: Yes, I got the equation. Thanks. But I have used log for dependent and independent variables so I have to do back transformation in both sides. How to do that ?